# How can I send the data from a imput type="file" to the controller?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I have in the ftl:

```
<input type="file" id="doc6" name="documente">
```

in .js:

```
var lx = $("#longX").val();
var ly = $("#latY").val();
var jud = $("#judetPunctLucru").val();
var doc6Type = $("#doc6Type").val();
var doc6 = $('doc6').val();

validateCoords: function (lx, ly, jud, doc6Type, doc6) {
            var data = {
                lx: lx,
                ly: ly,
                jud: jud,
                doc6Type: doc6Type,
                doc6: doc6
            };
            var url = contextPath + '/validareCoord';
            return getJSONData(url, data);
        }
```

and in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validareCoord", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getValidCoord(@RequestParam("lx") String lx,
                                             @RequestParam("ly") String ly,
                                             @RequestParam("jud") String jud,
                                             @RequestParam(value = "doc6Type", defaultValue = "") final String doc6Type,
                                             @RequestParam(value = "doc6", required=false) MultipartFile doc6){
.....
}
```

but doc6 is not what I need when I read it like that and the error is:

```
ERROR:
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
```

can you tell me how should I read the data from file? clearly `var doc6 = $('doc6').val();` it's not ok.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add headers in your `@RequestMapping` :

```
headers = "content-type=multipart/*"
```

Comment: I don't think it works with method = RequestMethod.GET

Comment: anyway, var doc6 = $('doc6').val() returns me... nothing

Comment: ok, I soved this by var doc6=document.getElementById("doc6");

Comment: That's because you forgot the #. `var doc6 = $('#doc6').val();`

Comment: yah, doc6 now, it's ok in JS but I still can't get the MultipartFile in the controller

Comment: Sorry that's as far as I can go. Sending a whole file content in a GET request seems a bit weird imho. What are you trying to achieve? Wouldn't it be easier to send only the few informations you need?

Comment: I have a shape file that contains information about some coords in a area and I have in the controller a service that extract the area from the shape file. I can't do that in the JS and I have to pass by the shape file so can I find out in what area are the coords...